# In Russian, how do you idiomatically express the idea of the figurative "overnight"?

Tags: выражения

In conversation, I just said:

> Нельзя **заснуть и наутро уже** все знать и уметь. Будь терпеливой. Ты получила права совсем недавно. То, что ты сумела столько продержаться с нами, – уже само по себе подвиг.

I went on a motorcycle ride with my girlfriend, who had obtained a driver's licence just recently. I wanted to express the idea of how one couldn't reasonably expect to get significantly better at something **overnight**.

The adverb "overnight" can be figuratively used when something changes/happens/etc surprisingly quickly. In French, the expression "du jour au lendemain" matches perfectly, but in Russian, this phrasing was the best I could come up with right there and then.

How do Russian speakers commonly express this idea?

Comment: The suggested "в одночасье" is a good idiomatic alternative, but in any case what you said sounds perfectly natural.

Comment: To mind comes the Russian proverb "Быстро хорошо не бывает."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**[В одночасье](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2_%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%B5)**

> Нельзя всё узнать и всему научиться **в одночасье**. Будь
>   терпеливой. Ты получила права совсем недавно. То, что ты сумела
>   столько продержаться с нами, – уже само по себе подвиг.

Simpler variants are **моментально, в (один) момент, мгновенно, в одно мгновение, в мгновение ока, мигом, за (один) день, тут же, сразу**

Comment: @svavil thank you

Comment: Нельзя всему научиться **вдруг** - жаль, что так уже не говорят. Красиво же...

Comment: В одночасье is not spoken Russian. I've never heard it used beyond literature courses and classics.

Comment: i have and would use it again, pretty neutral word, just good Russian, nothing fancy

Comment: i reside very far from St. Petersburg

Comment: can't call this comparison fair, these 1 + 2 words are unequal in frequency in general, but even 3 mil hits disprove the proposition that it's not a spoken word

Comment: this is a grotesque concoction of mixed registers, of course most native speakers don't talk such nonsense, but it has no bearing on the usability of **в одночасье**, you've fallen into a Straw Man logical fallacy in your arguments

Comment: just for the fun of it, let's compare with the disparity between English equivalents: **friend** - 2 bil 250 mil occurances, **overnight** - "a lousy" 319 mil, the difference is almost the same as between Russian counterparts, close to 1:10, so should we infer from this that **overnight** is not spoken English?

Comment: Ok, let's use a different source (частотный словарь). English word frequency - http://www.wordcount.org/main.php, russian word frequency http://www.artint.ru/projects/frqlist.php.  "overnight" is 7.6x less common than "friend" in English.
"одночасье" is 288x less common than "друг" in Russian.
How is your straw man feeling now?

Comment: but why Google results are no longer good enough? is it because they don't really support your contention? 1) the algorithms used by your two new resources are obviously markedly different, so again comparison between data provided by unequal sources 2) i've read the foreword to the Russsian frequency dictionary, it lists all its flaws which are many, just one quote **Слова** ***советский и товарищ*** **входят в первую сотню русских слов... слова** ***партия, революция, коммунистический*** **встречаются чаще чем** ***назад, около, лучше***, so not reliable

Comment: Why don't you provide a reliable source then? You are clearly very knowledgeable in this area, shouldn't be too hard for you.

Comment: because it's you who started the argument, not vice versa, so onus of proof is on you, for me the Google results you yourself provided are good enough, reference to my assumed knowledge and capabilities is another logical fallacy known as [Appeal to flattery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appeal_to_flattery), it's irrelevant to my being right or wrong and to refutation of my point of view

Answer (score 3):

Yes, we have a great variety of excellent proverbs about this, perhaps even more catchy and appealing than in other languages. Here are some examples:

1. Быстро только кошки родятся. Literal meaning: What happens quickly is only reproduction of cats. Global meaning: Everything takes time.
2. Москва не сразу строилась. Literal meaning: Moscow wasn't built instantly. Global meaning: Everything big is done gradually.
3. От нетерпения вода в котелке не закипит. Literal meaning: Impatience won't make the water in the pot boil. Global meaning: There's no use of impatience.
4. Терпи, казак, атаманом станешь. Literal meaning: Be patient (in enduring difficulties and sufferings), private, you will become a commander. Global meaning: Efforts and sufferings will pay off.

Here is a very Russian way to express what you want to express:

> Что, получила права и думала, что уже всё умеешь? Ага, разбежалась!
>   Быстро научиться нельзя, потому что быстро только кошки родятся. На
>   всякое хотенье имей терпенье, а от нетерпенья и вода в котелке не
>   закипит. Так что терпи, казачка. Атаманшей станешь! :)

Update: I did not add one important thing, assuming it goes without saying, but the comments below suggest it doesn't. The above example is humorous and has to be said in a proper manner, in a convincing but humorous and positive tone, with a smile on your face and with love in your eyes. The use of proverbs is supposed to be just the icing on the cake. The cake is your tone and facial expression. Overall, in such situations, it mainly boils down not to what you say, but to how you say. If you say the above speech in a wrong tone and with a wrong facial expression, it can do more harm than good :)

Comment: A perfect recipe to make one's girlfriend an ex :)

Comment: This "very Russian way" is uncommon and frankly cringeworthy, partly because it's so overloaded with proverbs. I don't know anyone who talks like that

Comment: @tum_ if I had an American boyfriend and he said this speech in Russian in a deeply convincing tone and with a charming smile, somewhat humorously, I would be very deeply impressed. It simply boils down not to what you say, but rather to how you say. Compare two situations: (1) A young girl says in a shy manner, ''Bring me one beer.'' (2) A big hulk says in an angry threatening tone, ''Would you bring me one beer please?!!!'' You get my point :)

Comment: A really small number of native Russian speakers talk like this. However, on average, Russian speakers do use proverbs more often than English speakers.

Answer (score 1):

> За ночь

would be most suitable for spoken language.

Which is by the way "over-night" translated literally.